# Angular routing between views

Tags: angular, routes

I have created a login page using Angular 7. I have created how the login page looks in the initial `app.component.html` file and I implemented the logic at `app.component.ts` file.

I also put a link "Forgot password". I put a router link redirecting to the `forgot-password.component.html`. The url changes correctly (from `localhost:4200` to `localhost:4200/forgot-password`) but the `forgot-password.component.html` is drawn on top of the previous login page.

http://prntscr.com/malk00

How can I erase the login page and go to the forgot password page?

Comment: I think best way to do this create `login` and `forgot password` separate component. add `<routeroutlet></routeroutlet>` in your appComponent. can you create small `https://stackblitz.com` for your problem.

Comment: can you share your router configuration code

Comment: There you go @Chellappan [link](https://pastebin.com/eesgAkLa).

Comment: Where is your login routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @abhishek, build the login component as a separate component. Only put the router outlet in the app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then change your routing to this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent }
];
```

That way the login page will route to the router outlet. And when the user clicks on the forgot password link, the entire page is replaced with the forgot-password component.

Answer (score 0):

Having the router from `import {Router} from '@angular/router';`, you can do this to redirect to another page `router.navigateByUrl('/forgot-password');`. It will then load the forgot password page.