# navigation between web page in angular

Tags: angular

I am developing an authentication web page for an authorization management application as you can see in this image:

[image: login page]

what I would like to do is when I click on the forgot login / password button a new page will appear which is this:

[image: forgot password]

the problem is that my code does not work here is what i did:

first here is the html code of my login page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login V1</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/login-page/images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/login-page/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/login-page/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/login-page/vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/login-page/vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/login-page/vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/login-page/css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/login-page/css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->


</head>
<body>

    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100">
            <div class="wrap-login100">
                <div class="login100-pic js-tilt" data-tilt>
                    <img src="/assets/login-page/images/img-01.png" alt="IMG">
                </div>

                <form class="login100-form validate-form">
                    <span class="login100-form-title">
                        Identifiant Telio Maroc 
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Nom de compte">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Password is required">
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn">
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center p-t-12">
                        <span class="txt1">
                            Forgot
                        </span>

                        <a class="txt2"  routerLink="/forgotpassword" routerLinkActive="active-link" >
                            Username / Password?

                        </a>


                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center p-t-136">
                        <a class="txt2" href="#">
                            Create your Account
                            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <script src="/assets/login-page/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="/assets/login-page/vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/login-page/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="/assets/login-page/vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="/assets/login-page/vendor/tilt/tilt.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >
        $('.js-tilt').tilt({
            scale: 1.1
        })
    </script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="/assets/login-page/js/main.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

you could see here that I used the routerlink

```
<a class="txt2"  routerLink="/forgotpassword" routerLinkActive="active-link" >
                            Username / Password?

</a>
```

and here is my login.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  /* 

  ForgotPassword = function () {
    this.router.navigate(['/forgotpassword']);
  };

  */
}
```

and here is my app-routing.module.ts page:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './components/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';


const routes: Routes = [

  {path: 'forgotpassword', component: ForgotPasswordComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and here is my module.ts page:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './components/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and here is my forgot_password.ts page:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forgot-password',
  templateUrl: './forgot-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forgot-password.component.css']
})
export class ForgotPasswordComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and here is my forgot_password.html page :

```
<!--Author: W3layouts
Author URL: http://w3layouts.com
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Reset Password Form  Responsive Widget Template | Home :: w3layouts</title>
<link href="/assets/forgot-password/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta name="keywords" content="Reset Password Form Responsive, Login form web template, Sign up Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Login signup Responsive web template, Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyEricsson, Motorola web design" />
<!--google fonts-->
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<!--element start here-->
<div class="elelment">
    <h2>Reset Password Form</h2>
    <div class="element-main">
        <h1>Forgot Password</h1>
        <p> Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut.</p>
        <form>
            <input type="text" value="Your e-mail address" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your e-mail address';}">
            <input type="submit" value="Reset my Password">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="copy-right">
            <p>© 2016 Reset Password Form. All rights reserved | Template by  <a href="http://w3layouts.com/" target="_blank">  W3layouts </a></p>
</div>

<!--element end here-->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do your component files have elements (such as `meta`, `title`, `link`) that are meant only in the document's `head` element?

Answer (score 0):

did you insert ("router-outlet") tag in app.html

From Angular Documentation:-

"Add your routes to your application.

Now that you have defined your routes, you can add them to your application.
Update your component template to include . This element informs Angular to update the application view with the component for the selected route."

Comment: no because when i add router-outlet it shows me my forgot password page inside my login page: /

(I'm a beginner in angular so if I make a mistake I want you to correct it  please :D)

Comment: You need a router outlet to navigate between components, 
try making a login page, and forget the password page as different components.

refer:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54310495/angular-routing-between-views?rq=1

Comment: I created 2 components one for the login and one for the forgot password each of them have an html page what I want to do is go from the login page to the forgot password page when I click on a button, is that not possible?